# Дублирование постов в соц. сети через WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

Подскажите, возможно ли дублирование постов на свой аккаунт в соц. сетях (VK, FB, INSTAGRAM) через блог на WordPress? Это нужно API писать либо есть плагин уже готовый?

Comment: как-то так https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/crossposting/.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Social-Publish и тд

Comment: Для этого существуют плагины кросспостинга. Гуглите их есть множество.